# Loading .txt file to MySQL database using Command Line Client

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL DB on my machine to use in my java website.
I've create the DB called cats.
I've also created my first table: user.
The user table has 2 columns: uname(VARCHAR 20) and pass(VARCHAR 20).

I want to populate the table with a simple .txt file I have on my desktop. 
I'm using:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/C:/Users/Rima/Desktop/userdata.txt' INTO TABLE pet
-> LINES TERMINATED BY '/r/n';
```

My .txt file contains 2 records - one in each line, and the 2 data columns separated by a tab.
rima pass 
u2 pass2

When I load my data I get 1 row.

How can I get this to load both records properly?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'

Comment: Are you sure they are terminated by CRLF?